# Resize photo to its original size not canvas size

Tags: resolution, images, adobe-photoshop, photos, canvas

I know about smart object , image size and canvas size and reveal all and trim in image menu and transform and other things.
But I want to if there is any solution to change size of canvas in relation to a photo.

think about it like this: you have 5 inch* 5inch 30 ppi canvas, you drag and drop a photo with size of 30inch*30inch 300 ppi to the canvas. it get fit automatically but picture looks so bad ( I know it is smart object and I know you can change the size and resolution of canvas manually) but is there anyway to change the size and resolution of canvas automatics in relation to photo, to see the photo in its real quality?

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution,
you just need to click on reset transform option in properties panel for image and after that select reveal all from image menu.